# Adding a column with different number of rows

Tags: r

I have two dataframes that I want to combine but I'm not sure how I would as one of them has a different number of columns. The first dataframe is this one:

```
Species Name                 Country           Lat         Lon  
Corynosoma hannae            New Zealand     -46.5000     170.3000
Polymorphus brevis           Mexico           19.4206    -102.2060
Acanthocephala terminalis    United States    38.1806    -83.4505
Polymorphus brevis           Mexico           30.5603    -115.9420
Polymorphus brevis           Mexico           19.6728    -99.7078
Polymorphus brevis           Mexico           19.6833    -101.8830
Polymorphus brevis           Mexico           30.5603    -115.9420
Polymorphus brevis           Mexico           30.5603    -115.9420
```

The second dataframe:

```
Species Name                 Country          Number of Records
Corynosoma hannae            New Zealand              3
Polymorphus brevis           Mexico                   41 
Acanthocephala terminalis    United States            1
```

The second dataframe tallies how many species samples were obtained for each country. I want to be able to add Number of Records to the first dataframe mainly be grouping such that the dataframe appears as so:

```
    Species Name                 Country           Lat         Lon       Number of Records  
    Corynosoma hannae            New Zealand     -46.5000     170.3000         3
    Acanthocephala terminalis    United States    38.1806    -83.4505          1
    Polymorphus brevis           Mexico           30.5603    -115.9420         41
    Polymorphus brevis           Mexico           19.6728    -99.7078
    Polymorphus brevis           Mexico           19.6833    -101.8830
    Polymorphus brevis           Mexico           30.5603    -115.9420
    Polymorphus brevis           Mexico           30.5603    -115.9420
    Acanthocephala confraterna   United States    35.6859    -83.4986           2
```

So I don't want to repeat, for example 41, for every row of Polymorphus brevis. I want it to just be one row that groups all of the Polymorphus brevis samples found in Mexico into the column Number of Records. Any help with this would be appreciated. I'm trying to create bubblemap with this dataframe using the rworldmap package.

Comment: Does dataframe 2 simply count the number of records in dataframe 1? If so there will be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: @Shree dataframe 2 tallies "Species Name" and "Country" which is present in dataframe 1. It shows how many samples of that species were collected from a specific country. Thus DF2 has 38 rows while DF1 has 56.

Comment: I added an answer based on your above comment. See if it works for you. If not, I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our comments a simpler solution might be to add a new column to dataframe 1 rather that joining two dataframes -

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(`Species Name`, Country) %>%
  mutate(
    nRecords = ifelse(row_number() == 1, n(), NA_integer_)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: I tried this and I got the following error 'Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types.'

Comment: see if my edit helps. If not, add the output of `dput(head(your_dataframe))` to your post.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by = c("Species Name", "Country")) %>%
  group_by(`Species Name`, Country) %>%
  mutate(
    `Number of Records` = as.numeric(as.character(`Number of Records`)),
    `Number of Records` = ifelse(row_number() == 1, `Number of Records`, NA)
    )
```

Comment: I did as you said and I got the following error: 'Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `false` must be type character, not double
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace.'

Comment: I tried the edit and i get the following error: 'Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `false` must be type integer, not character
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace.'

Comment: I think your `Number of Records` is probably a character or even factor; I've amended my solution and think this should apply to your dataframe as well regardless of the types.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the two previous answers suggesting to simply add a new column to one data frame with info from the other data frame. One way of doing this is by using the function `match()`:

```
# define 1st df:
df1 <- data.frame( 
  Observations = c("obs1", "obs2", "obs3"),
  Data = c(sample(1:20, 3))
  )

# define 2nd df:
df2 <- data.frame( 
  OtherObservations = c("obs1", "obs2", "obs3"),
  OtherData = c(1, 2, NA)
)

# now add to df1 the relevant column in df2 based on matching data in either data frame:
df1$NewColumn <- df2$OtherData[match(df1$Observations, df2$OtherObservations)]
df1
```